# Correct joining of this regex for password confirmation

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, passwords

Trying to create a jquery function that checks if the password meets the certain requirments, password must contain at least 3 characters being uppercase, numbers or special characters. This can be a mix of the 3, so could be 2 uppercase and 1 special etc....

I have created a function which checks using regex but its very long, I know it can be joined together but I cant seem to figure out how.

```
$('#Password').blur(function () {
        var pswd = $(this).val();
        if (pswd.length > 7) {
            if (pswd.match(/(?=(.*[A-Z].*){3,}).{7,}/) // 3 caps
                ||
                pswd.match(/(?=(.*\W.*){3,}).{7,}/) // 3 special chars
                ||
                pswd.match(/(?=(.*\d.*){3,}).{7,}/) // 3 digits
                ||
                (pswd.match(/(?=(.*[A-Z].*){2,})/ && pswd.match(/(?=(.*\W.*){1,})/))) // 2 caps 1 special
                ||
                (pswd.match(/(?=(.*[A-Z].*){1,})/ && pswd.match(/(?=(.*\W.*){2,})/))) // 1 cap 2 special
                ||
                (pswd.match(/(?=(.*[A-Z].*){2,})/ && pswd.match(/(?=(.*\d.*){1,})/))) // 2 cap 1 digit
                ||
                (pswd.match(/(?=(.*[A-Z].*){1,})/ && pswd.match(/(?=(.*\d.*){2,})/))) // 1 cap 2 digit
                ||
                (pswd.match(/(?=(.*\W.*){2,})/ && pswd.match(/(?=(.*\d.*){1,})/))) // 2 special 1 digit
                ||
                (pswd.match(/(?=(.*\W.*){1,})/ && pswd.match(/(?=(.*\d.*){2,})/))) // 1 special 2 digit
                ||
                (pswd.match(/(?=(.*\W.*){1,})/ && pswd.match(/(?=(.*\d.*){1,})/) && pswd.match(/(?=(.*[A-Z].*){1,})/)))
            ) // 1 of each /
            {
                $('#Message').hide();
            }
        } else {
            $('#Message').show();
        }
    });
```

The function works fine but I want to improve the regex, is it possible to do the same password check in better time or reduction of code.

Comment: I know i can join whats in side each OR condition with a . but is there a better and more efficient way.

Comment: "*but its very long, I know it can be joined together*" you want to make a single regex or do you want to just make your function to be more readable?

Comment: Single regex is what I'm looking for, I'm not sure if its even achievable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about if you count the special character occurrence in the string, like:

```
pswd.match(/(?=[A-Z])|(?=[0-9])|(?=[#$^+=!*()@%&])/g).length
```

...and compare with '3' in your case.

@PJProudhon - Thanks for the suggestion:

```
pswd.match(/[A-Z]|[0-9]|[#$^+=!*()@%&]/g).length
```

Comment: I like this, that's a great solution. Thank you.

Comment: For this match the look-ahead is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Focus on "must contain at least 3 characters being uppercase, numbers or special characters".

You can express it as: contains at least 3 characters which are not lower case. That way no join is even needed here.

I'll give a try to `^(?=(?:[a-z]*[^a-z]){3}).{7,}$`.

Comment: OK, you win, my bad